# Alsamixer missing controls after upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: alsa

We previously loaded Ubuntu 10.04 on our Q7 intel platform + custom hardware that uses the Intel HDA sound card.  Sound worked well.

We changed to 12.04 yesterday and have output (speaker) sound, but no "line" input sound.  Interestingly, alsamixer is now missing the control labeled "digital" under 10.04.  There is a new SPDIF control present in 12.04 but it has neither mute nor sliders;  It's just  there.

Another interesting tidbit, if it helps, the sound test built into the sound control will play "Left front", but not "right front", even though the stereo outputs are connected together and tied to one speaker.

I have already done a alsactl init followed by a reboot.

Here is the current output of amixer.

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 217 [85%] [-7.60dB]
  Front Right: Playback 217 [85%] [-7.60dB]
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Capture channels: Mono
  Mono: Capture [on]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 16 [52%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 16 [52%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',1
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 0 [0%] [-12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 0 [0%] [-12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',2
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 3 [10%] [-7.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 3 [10%] [-7.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Line'
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',1
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Mic'
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',2
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Mic'
```

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I know I had a very low right channel after initial install until I adjusted the mixer settings and it seemed to suddenly come to life. have you adjusted ALL of the mixer settings?